# NGINX is giving 502 bad gateway but working fine with Apache2 on Ubnatu 14.04

Tags: php, nginx, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

php5 over nginx is giving 502 bad gateway but working fine with apache2.Am running Apache on default port and nginx on port 81.

error log message:

```
2016/12/02 12:32:05 [alert] 10119#0: 768 worker_connections are not enough
2016/12/02 12:32:05 [error] 10119#0: *2295 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while 
reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: 
"GET /index.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:81/index.php", host: "127.0.0.1".
```

My custom server file:

```
server {
    listen   81;
    root /var/www/html/laralvelproj/public/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/www/html/yoyogrx.com-error.log error;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
     }
}
```

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: So you got your nginx listening on port 81 and proxying the same, that is wrong.

Comment: Then what I can do here..I haven't fixed yet :(

Comment: then proxy your upstream, not nginx itself, find out at what port php(if upstream) is listening and proxy that.